# Bootstrap3: Fixed navbar in mobile layout is expanded by default on load without 'in' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put in a menu in a page running off of a Bootstrap template. When I load the page in a window below 960px the mobile version of the menu is already expanded (and covering a large part of my content). There is no 'in' class in the navbar on load, but if I click it, it remains there, and then I click the toggle button again, and it collapses. After the first click the 'in' class appears, but I can't figure out a way to collapse the menu by default on first load. Any ideas?

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">

<div id="wrap">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="menu">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="./images/chalmers-avancez2.png" alt=""  /></a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#program">Program</a></li>
                <li><a href="#speakers">Speakers / Performers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a id="SV" href="#SV">SV</a></li>
                <li><a id="EN" href="#EN">EN</a></li> 
            </ul>  
        </div>

    </div>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `collapse` but you also are adding the `navbar` on it, which is incorrect:

INCORRECT:

```
<div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar navbar-collapse">
```

CORRECT:

```
<div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/koqas/1/edit**